# Angular - Table with expandable row (hierarchy structure)

Tags: angular, angular-material, expandable, angular-material-table, expandable-table

I have hierarchy structure data which I'm trying to show in the table. I'm using material-table expandable which works fine when I show only one level of data.

I created a table that shows the main data and when I click on detail it showing another table expanded.

I have more and more data for sub-detail which I need to show.

I moved an expanded table to ng-template and I'm passing params with let-param but the problem I'm facing when I click the first level shows fine but when I click the second level it's hiding the first level.

Please let me know if anyone has experience with this type of task.

Thank you.

Comment: Forks,

Found a solution. If someone needs how to implement just let me know. 

Thanks

Comment: Hello @Temurjon Mahmudov  I have asked similar question a while ago, could you please check this and let me know if you have any resolution for same : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69717559/generating-and-displaying-nested-angular-material-table-dynamically